# What are the proper typescript types for addEventListener mousemove and its event argument?

Tags: typescript, mouseevent, mousemove, tsc, static-typing

**Question:** Without using `any`, what is the proper typing for my `onMouseMove` function?

```
export class Main {
  private dTimer: number;

  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }

  private init() {
    this.mouseHandlers();
  }

  private mouseHandlers() {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove)
  }

  private onMouseMove: EventListener = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    clearTimeout(this.dTimer);
    this.dTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(event.pageX, event.pageY)
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

Typescript is complaining about my types, and I don't know how to make it happy without using `any`.

```
main.ts(38,3): error TS2322: Type '(event: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'evt' are incompatible.
    Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'MouseEvent'.
      Property 'altKey' is missing in type 'Event'.
```

Comment: Event handler receives a MouseEventInit Type. Tell parameter it's a MouseEvent.
…addEventListener("mousemove", (ev: MouseEventInit): void => dosomething(ev as MouseEvent));

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> What are the proper typescript types for addEventListener mousemove and it's event argument?

Being explicit will set you free:

```
onMouseMove: { (event: MouseEvent): void } = (event: MouseEvent) => {
}
```

Or, let TypeScript infer it from assignment :

```
onMouseMove = (event: MouseEvent) => {
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I've found that using `MouseEventInit` as the event type solves the problem.  This type comes from TypeScript `lib.dom.ts`. I'm using TypeScript 4.5.5.
i.e.

```
private onMouseMove: EventListener = (event: MouseEventInit) => {
clearTimeout(this.dTimer);
this.dTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(event.pageX, event.pageY)
}, 500);}
```

Comment: `preventDefault()` doesn't exist on `MouseEventInit` :(

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into this issue with React and wanted to call out that when adding a mouse event listener to the **window**, or any DOM element, not a React component, we need to use the global DOM MouseEvent type, no import needed. If you use VSCode like me, you may have accidentally auto-imported MouseEvent from React! If so, just remove that import and you'll be good to go. Hope this helps someone, cheers!

Comment: Thx! that was the actual fix

Answer (score 5):

There is no need for explcit type in this case, because type of your function will be checked when you assign your handler to event. Look for example to `onclick`:

```
onclick: (this: HTMLElement, ev: MouseEvent) => any;
```

There type of `onclick` handler. When you will write:

```
myDomElement.onclick = myFunction;
```

TypeScript will check whenever `myFunction` match `onclick` type. So, just let TypeSript infer type, as another answer said.