# Assigning a type to an event handler in a custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a custom `useEventListener` hook that I've derived from [here](https://usehooks.com/useEventListener/), and I just started learning Typescript, so I decided to rewrite it into a typed version.

Here's the hook that I have,

```
const useEventListener = (
  eventName: string,
  handler: any,
) => {
  const savedHandler: any = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    savedHandler.current = handler
  }, [handler])

  useEffect(() => {
    const eventListener: any = (event: KeyboardEvent) => savedHandler.current(event)

    window.addEventListener(eventName, eventListener);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener(eventName, eventListener)
    }
  }, [eventName])
}
```

And I use it as,

```
const keyPressHandler = useCallback(({ key }: KeyboardEvent) => {
  if (key === 'ArrowUp')
    // do something
  else if (key === 'ArrowDown')
    // do something else
})

useEventListener('keydown', keyPressHandler)
```

It's a relatively simple setup, but I've been banging my head on the typing aspect. Getting rid of the `any` in

```
const savedHandler: any = useRef()
```

or in

```
const eventListener: any = (. . .
```

makes the compiler complain, and I don't know how to get around this. What type is `savedHandler` in this case? And for `const eventListener`, why does it even need a type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the saveHandler you can type the useRef as followed:

`const savedHandler = useRef<YOURHTMLELEMENTTYPE>();`

For YOURHTMLELEMENTTYPE you can choose any of the [following](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.htmlelement.html), it depends on the the element your referring to.

For the eventListener I would recommend [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49226309/what-are-the-proper-typescript-types-for-addeventlistener-mousemove-and-its-eve). I think this post describes your exact problem.

Comment: It's not an HTMLElement though, it's still erroring out. In the link you sent, there's also a listeners section: would one of those work?

Comment: Ahh I did not see that. So I think you will have to type your handler first. The type for your handler will look something like this: `type keyHandlerEvent = (KeyboardEvent) => void` and you can use this type for both the `handler` and the `saveHandler` instead of the `any` which you use right now.