# TypeScript mousemove event on window

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events, mouseevent

I am trying to log the event on `mousemove` on `window` in the console using React with TypeScript. After some research and looking at [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49226309/what-are-the-proper-typescript-types-for-addeventlistener-mousemove-and-its-eve) I thought I could use `MouseEvent` as the type for the event passed on to the listener.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const onMouseMove = (e: MouseEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
  };

  window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
  };
}, []);
```

But when running, it prompts me the following error:

```
const onMouseMove: (e: MouseEvent) => void
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "mousemove", listener: (this: Window, ev: MouseEvent) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(e: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Window, ev: MouseEvent) => any'.
      Types of parameters 'e' and 'ev' are incompatible.
        Type 'MouseEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>': nativeEvent, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped, persist
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(e: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
      Type '(e: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.
        Types of parameters 'e' and 'evt' are incompatible.
          Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>': altKey, button, buttons, clientX, and 18 more
```

I tried updating my event listener syntax with some of the suggestions but none of them seem to fix the problem.

```js
const onMouseMove = (e: MouseEvent): any => {} // any as return type
const onMouseMove: EventListener = (e: MouseEvent) => {} // type as EventListener
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the proper typescript types for addEventListener mousemove and it's event argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49226309/what-are-the-proper-typescript-types-for-addeventlistener-mousemove-and-its-eve)

Comment: @guzmonne I provided this link in the question and tried the answers, maybe I did something wrong, could you point out what?

Comment: @axtck, does you have any `import { MouseEvent } from "react";` if so, remove that import MouseEvent, the event type for window is MouseEvent (DOM) not the one from React

Comment: @somallg I was indeed using the `MouseEvent` from React, thank you!

Comment: @somallg could you add your solution as answer? Might be handy for other people to see.

Comment: @axtck i add my solution, please check it out

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please note that React has it's own definition of MouseEvent (and other Event as well)

When you add event handler to React Element you have to use React Event

```
<div onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent) => { console.log(e) }></div>
```

But if you add event listener using DOM API, make sure it come from DOM

```
  // DOM Event not to be confused with React.MouseEvent
  const onMouseMove = (e: MouseEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
  };

  window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
  };
```

TypeScript supports DOM event of of the box. In case you import Event from react

```
import { MouseEvent } from 'react';
```

This will override MouseEvent of DOM and TypeScript will not happy since those 2 types are differents

Comment: This is key, thanks! VSCode automatically imported MouseEvent from React which was my issue. Need to use the global DOM MouseEvent type, no import required!